# Decoding wpa-psk traffic with Wireshark

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, wireshark, monitoring

I want to plot how much data each client is using from a wpa-psk protected access point (that I control). For that I intend to monitor all traffic for a couple of days. However I can't decode the TCP data.

I did as specified here, adding my raw key to Wireshark: https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

I used this tool to generate it from the pre-shared key and SSID: https://www.wireshark.org/tools/wpa-psk.html

But I only get the raw `data` fields with base64 content:

```
Frame 1181: 161 bytes on wire (1288 bits), 161 bytes captured (1288 bits) on interface 0
Radiotap Header v0, Length 48
802.11 radio information
IEEE 802.11 QoS Data, Flags: .p....F..
Data (75 bytes)
    Data: aaaa0300000008004500003b000040003a11df93d83ac6c3...
    [Length: 75]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution is to ignore the Protection bit.**

In Preferences -> Protocols -> IEEE 802.11:
[image]

In found the solution [from this old Wireshark mail list](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200608/msg00062.html).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why wireshark is unable to do this automatically, but you can see the [IPv4 header](http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/inet-pages/ip-packet.html) in the "Data" portion:

```
45 => version/header length
00 => ToS
003b => Length (= 59 bytes)
0000 => Identifier
4000 => Flags + Frag offset
3a => TTL
11 => Protocol (0x11 = 17 = UDP)
df93 => Header Checksum
d83ac6c3 => Source IP address (216.58.198.195)
```

(Last 4 bytes = Dest IP address not available from your post. Try the -x option to get tshark to print the entire frame in hex).

The data preceding the IPv4 header is the [SNAP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork_Access_Protocol):

```
aa aa 03 000000 0800
```